# Lync 2010 incoming normalization

Tags: lync

Can anyone help with normalizing *incoming* numbers from our audiocodes mediant 1000 (from PSTN) box into lync. Out the box, numbers are presented to lync without a leading zero, so eg a local london number comes through as 208 123 1234. Here's what ive tried:

Add normalization rule for these number in a user dial plan (test 208 123 1234 normalizes to 0208 123 1234)
Add similar normalization rule to a pool dial plan using the audiocodes gateway

I see From:sip:23081231234... in the logs, some of them have phone-context=UK (is the context the dial plan its using?)

These all test fine, and show the correct normalized number, but the incoming calls still do not seem to be normalized - is there something I'm missing?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lync Dialing Rule Optimizer to normalize all those incoming rules. it creates as automatically all normalization rules.

Link : http://www.lyncoptimizer.com/

Comment: This creates normalization rules, just like ive done (in fact some are identical). These alse test just fine, they also present the same (incorrect) number to lync client for incoming calls. Outgoing calls are normalized just fine

Comment: I've been using those normalization rules that creates via link. Outgoing and incoming calls are normalized very-well. if it comes incorrectly normalized number to the Lync Client side you need to look gateway side as well.

Comment: Selahattin, do you normalize incoming on your gateway?